# sort file based one colum and group by another column

Tags: linux, files, awk, sort, group

I have a file of three columns:

```
1   A     0.5
2   B     0.7
3   A     10
4   C     4
5   B     4
```

I want to sort the file by increasing order of column 3 and group by column 2

```
1  A   0.5
3  A   10
2  B   0.7
5  B   4
4  C   4
```

I know how to sort only based on the 3rd column :

```
sort -k3,3 file
```

But can we  group by the second column ?

Comment: What do mean when you say "group"? Do you need to retain field 2 file order? If not `sort -k2,2 -k3,3n  file` should do

Comment: yes your command does what I want thanks you can add the answer @1_CR

Answer (score 1):

sort by the third column, then by the second:

```
$ sort -k3,3 file | sort -k 2,2
```

output:

```
1   A   0.5
3   A   10
2   B   0.7
5   B   4
4   C   4
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no answer, so my suggestion

```
sort -k2,2 -nk3,3 file
```

Comment: `n` before `k` in `-nk3,3` is a global option (equivalent to `-n -k3,3`), which makes the second column sort fail.
You should use `-k3,3n` (or `-k3n,3`) instead.